# Pact JS - The pact mock service wasn't running when verify was called

Tags: pact

When I run my Pact tests I get the following error - "The pact mock service wasn't running when verify was called".

The project I am running tests in is in GitHub - https://github.com/pactflow/example-consumer/tree/master/src

I run the tests using this command - npm t

See error in my detail below -

> ```
> The pact mock service wasn't running when verify was called
> ```

```
  12 | describe('API Pact test', () => {
  13 |   beforeAll(() => mockProvider.setup());
> 14 |   afterEach(() => mockProvider.verify());
     |                                ^
  15 |   afterAll(() => mockProvider.finalize());
  16 |
  17 |   describe('retrieving a product', () => {

  at Pact.verify (node_modules/@pact-foundation/src/httpPact.ts:136:9)
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/api.pact.spec.js:14:32)
```

Comment: Set logging to debug level and look at the terminal output. You should see an error while it tries to start the mock service. Usually it's due to a port conflict

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that the path to my project was too long. I read that Pact only allows 80 characters for path lengths.

Comment: Hi, and how did you solve this?, I have the same issue

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error: `The pact mock service wasn't running when verify was called` but looking at the debug logs seemed that it was throwing

```
 thrown: "Exceeded timeout of 5000 ms for a hook.
    Use jest.setTimeout(newTimeout) to increase the timeout value, if this is a long-running test."
```

to fix it, I added the code below, as suggested by izhaoqing [here](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/11607).

```
// jest.config.js
module.exports = {
    // ...
    testTimeout: 20000
}
```

Seems to be related to version 27 of jest as another project with 26 is working fine.